# Why some .h file have two classes?

Tags: ios, objective-c

All of my .h file in my project just have one class in each file.But I see that UIAlertController.h file has two classes :UIAlertController and UIAlertAction.Why Apple designed this and when should we combine two or more classes in one file？

Comment: Typically, one class per file is a pattern commonly followed. If the classes are closely linked, then sometimes people will put them in the same file.

Comment: Or protocol (e.g. for class delegate) + class. Or a class and extension. Sometimes it just does not make sense to create a separate file to define a simple data holder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.h` files are header files, they contain references to all the functions you define in your `.m` file, so that you can share code across multiple files. You can define as many classes and functions in you `.m` file as you want, thus, you can reference as many classes and function as you need in your '.m' file, so you can use them in other source files. Combining two or more classes in a `.h` file depends on if you defined two or more classes in the corresponding `.m` file.

Comment: Technically in Objective-C they are .m files. For clarity.

Comment: @NateBirkholz, thank you, I'll edit it so it doesn't confuse anyone.